# Angular ensure toggle is closed if another one is opened

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle

Have two different divs that can be toggled open and closed in Angualar app but trying to make sure that if one is opened that the other one closes. Seems like this should be simple enough in NG but still new to Angular. Anyone have any pointers?

Made an example fiddle here:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q7hrpc5/1/)

Here is the sample:

```
 <body ng-app="simpleToggle">
   <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <button ng-click="toggleCustom1()">Custom</button>
    <span ng-hide="custom1">
        <h2>Custom 1 is showing but Custom 2 should not be if it was already opened</h2>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="custom1"></span>
</div>

<div ng-controller="App2Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="toggleCustom2()">Custom2</button>
    <span ng-hide="custom2">
        <h2>Custom 2 is showing but Custom 1 should not be if it was already opened.</h2>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="custom2"></span>
</div>
 </body>

 angular.module('simpleToggle', [])
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.custom1 = true;
    $scope.toggleCustom1 = function() {
        $scope.custom1 = $scope.custom1 === false ? true: false;
    };
 }])
.controller('App2Ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.custom2 = true;
    $scope.toggleCustom2 = function() {
        $scope.custom2 = $scope.custom2 === false ? true: false;
    };
 }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are dealing with the scope hierarchy, you wil want to use one of the mechanisms to coordinate between controllers. Some options are:

1. Using the $rootScope
2. Using messages

I have updated your example to use $rootScope here http://jsfiddle.net/4q7hrpc5/3/

firstly, create something to initialize the $rootScope. I created an outer controller and wrapped the two other controllers in that controller. Here is the updated HTML:

```
<body ng-app="simpleToggle">
    <div ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            <button ng-click="toggleCustom1()">Custom</button>
            <span ng-hide="!custom1">
                <h2>Custom 1 is showing but Custom 2 should not be if it was already opened</h2>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="App2Ctrl">
            <button ng-click="toggleCustom2()">Custom2</button>
            <span ng-hide="!custom2">
                <h2>Custom 2 is showing but Custom 1 should not be if it was already opened.</h2>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

here is the code for the controllers:

```
angular.module('simpleToggle', [])
    .controller('OuterCtrl', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.custom1 = false;
        $rootScope.custom2 = false;
    }])
    .controller('AppCtrl',['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
        $scope.toggleCustom1 = function() {
            $rootScope.custom1 = !$rootScope.custom1;
            $rootScope.custom2 = false;
        };
}])
    .controller('App2Ctrl',['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope){
        $scope.toggleCustom2 = function() {
            $rootScope.custom2 = !$rootScope.custom2;
            $rootScope.custom1 = false;
        };
}]);
```

Now this specific technique only works well for a small number of things that have to be coordinated. Messages or a service might be better if you have a large number of these things that need to be coordinated. Another alternative would be to put them all into the same controller.

Comment: Perfect you the man. Right now I just have the two but that are in two separate views using the ui-router and in multiple pages/views. Thank you. In my app though I do not have a master controller (outerCtrl) so I may need to bind it to the global run or config.

Comment: Worked good and able to do it without wrapping an outer controller. Thanks again... My poor jQuery mind is once again blown!  http://jsfiddle.net/4q7hrpc5/4/

Comment: Here is an example without an outer controller, using a service http://jsfiddle.net/4q7hrpc5/5/

Comment: Right on. Probably use that example if I need to extend it. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice! Thanks @unobf for posting this solution. I'm deleting my answer because this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice for handling DOM Stuffs using directive. I use `.next()` for getting the next span. or you can use other selector for getting it.

documentation for elem: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

working here  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cJheuL005GWAt1d14LoQ?p=preview)

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
        <button change-toggle>Custom</button>
        <span id="span1" class="toggle-show-css">
            <h2>Custom 1 is showing but Custom 2 should not be if it was already opened</h2>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button change-toggle>Custom2</button>
        <span id="span2" class="toggle-show-css">
            <h2>Custom 2 is showing but Custom 1 should not be if it was already opened.</h2>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
.toggle-hide-css {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.toggle-show-css {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

directive

```
app.directive('changeToggle', ['$location', function($location) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function(event) {
        var spanner = elem.next();
        if(spanner.hasClass("toggle-show-css")) {
          elem.parent().parent().find('span').removeClass("toggle-show-css");
          elem.parent().parent().find('span').addClass("toggle-hide-css");
          spanner.removeClass("toggle-show-css");
          spanner.addClass("toggle-hide-css");
        } else {
          elem.parent().parent().find('span').removeClass("toggle-show-css");
          elem.parent().parent().find('span').addClass("toggle-hide-css");
          spanner.removeClass("toggle-hide-css");
          spanner.addClass("toggle-show-css");
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```